# Flask: Why does my server stall when I 'import requests'?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, ibm-cloud-code-engine

**SCENARIO**

I am using a python flask server to serve up data from my remote database. I am tempting to use the `requests` framework to connect to my database with a held connection.

**TECHNOLOGY USED**

- **Python** 3.10
- **Flask** 2.0.3
- **Poetry** 1.0 (for dependencies)
- **Requests** 2.28.1 (added with Poetry)
- **IBM Code Engine** (cloud platform/environment)

**ISSUE**

My project works just fine up until I add the line `import request` at the top of my `server.py`. When I add this line no responses are given by my server and it times out.

**CODE**

> The below outputs `{ "hello": "there" }`, because `import requests` was not added.

```
import os
import sys
import json
from collections import Counter
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, url_for, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
    return { 'hello': "there" }

if __name__ == 'main':
    app.run()
```

> The below stalls and servers no response, because `import requests` **was** added.

```
import os
import sys
import json
import requests # adding this
from collections import Counter
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, url_for, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
    return { 'hello': "there" }

if __name__ == 'main':
    app.run()
```

**QUESTION**

Why can't I import requests, and if I'm missing something could you please leave a code answer as to what I need to do to get this working?

(I've noticed some other frameworks can't be imported either)

Comment: Running your server under `python -m trace` is a good place to start.

Comment: A [MRE] that hangs the same way when running on someone else's system would also be very helpful. Consider trying to reproduce in an online sandbox like https://repl.it/ to verify. (Unfortunately, not many of us have access to IBM's execution environment).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm sort of new to Flask and Server side development in general. So, in your experience being able to import requests never produces this result? Or is this a common problem?

Comment: Importing requests is surely very common pattern and as such does not normally produce any errors.

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but, this actually isn't producing errors. It's just timing out. Do you think that it's doing some asynchronous work that I need to wait for and my 10 min timeout isn't enough? That seems strange.

Comment: Indeed, it's not at all normal. I would expect that there's a different module being imported shadowing `requests` or one of its dependencies, which is part of why I suggested figuring out what it takes to reproduce this in a different environment (potentially using the standard-library `trace` module to figure exactly where in interpreter startup or the import process the hang is taking place as an aid to that reproducer's development).

Comment: There are places where anomalies in a system environment can cause usually-fast operations to block (unavailable DNS infrastructure causing long timeouts when something tries to do a hostname lookup; failed network filesystems causing mount-table enumeration to hang; etc), but _in general_ (1) it's bad form for module initialization to do any of that behind one's back; and (2) because those problems tend to be unique to a given system, the same code won't necessarily trigger them without identical configuration anomalies. So there's a very good chance we really can't help without a [mre].

Comment: Besides the python questions, where I am not an expert, I have two other questions: 
a) How are you building this code ? Through a docker and then deploy the dockerfile or are you using Code Engine's built-in buildpacks to do that ? 
b) When you say "stalled" - does that mean the app builds and deploys, but then the server doesn't respond ?
If the former, you should make sure to set the right port in the Dockerfile and the app should use multi-stage build to reduce image size. Note that this is not directly related to the import issue, but might give you other areas to investigate